# MVC 4 WebAPI json array hijacking

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-web-api

I have ApiConroller with method looking like that:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<MyValue> Values()
{
     return db.MyValues.ToList();
}
```

It returns a JSON array. I use jQuery to get results. How do I keep that array from being hijacked, smth like autonesting, etc.?

Comment: What do you mean by *hijacking*? How exactly your JSON will be *hijacked*? What are you trying to protect against?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I think he's referring to the JavaScript array constructor vulnerability, http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/24/json-hijacking.aspx

Comment: Oh I see. Then your answer is straight to the point. +1 from me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it in a generic way.

Add the following class:

```
public class SecureJsonMediaTypeFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, System.IO.Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        if ((typeof (IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type)))
        {
            value = new {result = value};
        }
        return base.WriteToStreamAsync(type, value, writeStream, content, transportContext);
    }
}
```

And now, in your WebApiConfig replace the default `JSonMediaTypeFormatter` with this new one:

```
    config.Formatters.RemoveAt(0);
    config.Formatters.Insert(0, new SecureJsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Now you can return any IEnumerable you wish, like you originally did, i.e.

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<MyValue> Values()
{
     return db.MyValues.ToList();
}
```

And the `SecureJsonMEdiaTypeFormatter` will intercept it, and wrap in an anonymous object, under `result` property:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "name": "Toronto Maple Leafs",
            "league": "NHL"
        },
        {
            "name": "Montreal Canadiens",
            "league": "NHL"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Though I decided that any server side autonesting makes API more obscure, I can't help but like you way of doing it!

Comment: alternatively you could just implement an xsrf token to validate requests

Answer (score 3):

You could simply wrap your result in an object.

```
   return new { values = db.MyValues.ToList() };
```

Because a JavaScript object isn't a valid script, this prevents the result from being executed maliciously, as Haack explains at http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/24/json-hijacking.aspx

Comment: I used that, just thought there is a more elegant and automated way for wrapping collection in every method like that without changing result type and adding more noise.